# jquery-modal plugin explicit invocation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

I'm using a 2-step templating system to generate web pages.  A *main* content section is generated first, and **this** is the content which will typically want to attach [jQuery modal](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)s to various elements.  The second pass wraps that into the actual *base* HTML page (header, body, standard menu, etc.).

jQuery is always loaded  in the *base* HTML, just before the `</body>` tag as is best practice.  Clearly, the jQuery modal will not function until jQuery itself is loaded.  But only *main* content templates know if they need the modal.

I have a couple other jQuery plugins I use, and I get around this problem by simply pushing a call to them on a stack of callbacks.  After jQuery is loaded, the callbacks are all called sequentially by a small snippet of Javascript just before the `</body>` tag.  Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to do this with jQuery modal, because [the code](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal/blob/master/jquery.modal.js) looks like this:

```
(function (factory) {
  // ...
}(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  // ...
}));
```

In other words, jQuery modal is invoked immediately upon being encountered on the HTML page -- well before jQuery itself is loaded -- because of the enclosing `( ... )`.

Is there some way I can cause explicit invocation of the jQuery modal code *only after* jQuery has actually been loaded?

Comment: "*In other words, jQuery modal is invoked immediately upon being encountered o....*" no it's not. It's just a common IIFE pattern to encapsulate code into closure. Has nothin to do with your problem. Just invoke modal manually yourself.

Comment: I'm confused.   _"IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined."_ -- Mozilla docs.  Yet you say it's not invoked.  The behavior I observe is my reference of `<script src="/res/js/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>` causes the modal script to be invoked, but it fails to work because jQuery is not yet referenced.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: IIFE is invoked of course. I don't understood what `jQuery modal is invoked`. Anyway. don't include this script before jQuery.